# Can you design a DC motor with any arbitrary torque speed curve?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, torque, speed

Title pretty much says it all. I have a low-rpm (30-160) and moderate-torque (2 N-m) application. These characteristics are pretty easy to hit with an off-the-shelf dc motor + gearbox. But let's say I wanted to avoid the gearbox, can you design the dc motor windings/magnets for any arbitrary torque-speed curve? What are the consequences of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, and any motor (at least any PMSM brushless motor) that can produce 2 Nm can be operated at 30 rpm.  However, motors that can produce this torque without a gearbox will necessarily have a larger rotor and will be running at a low efficiency.  So you must first find a motor that can produce your torque, then run it at a low voltage, and your controller will need feedback to give you rotor position to apply the correct current to each phase to make it run smoothly.

A drawback is that since current is proportional to torque, you will experience the same resistive losses at low speeds that you would at higher speeds, giving you poor efficiency.  There are motors specially designed for high torque at low speeds - they have extremely large diameter rotors and many poles.  Some examples are at https://www.mclennan.co.uk/datasheet/1847.  But in general for size and efficiency, gearmotors are the best solution.

Brush motors and motors with hall feedback are problematic because of the torque ripple that results from not having good rotor position.  At 30 rpm, you would experience a "jerky" motion in the shaft position.